# how use df.loc em pandas with inside a for?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting the error, KeyError, when running pandas' df.loc on PANDAS, with Selenium-webdriver. The worksheet has an "OBS" column that must be filled according to the execution of the code below.
I thing is something with this line: `df.loc[df[row["NOME"]], ["OBS"]] = resultado` How to fix this error?

```
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Value
from pickle import FALSE, TRUE
from tkinter.tix import COLUMN
from typing import KeysView
from unicodedata import decimal
from numpy import column_stack
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook



from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


PATH = "chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

arquivo_excel = 'escolas.xlsx'


df = pd.read_excel(arquivo_excel)
df.round(2)

for index,row in df.iterrows():  
    print("index:" + str(index) + "E o nome da pessoa é " + row["NOME"])

    driver.get("https://aps.bvs.br/apps/calculadoras/?page=7")

    sleep(1)
    peso = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'peso')
    altura = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'altura')
    anos = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'anos')
    meses = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'meses')
    dias = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'dias')
    

    sleep(1)
    peso.send_keys(row['PESO'])
    altura.send_keys(row['ALTURA'])
    anos.send_keys(row['ANOS'])
    meses.send_keys(row['MESES'])
    dias.send_keys(row['DIAS'])
    # sexo.send_keys(row['SEXO'])
    dias.send_keys(Keys.TAB + Keys.RETURN)
    resultado = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'result').text

    df.loc[df[row["NOME"]], ["OBS"]] = resultado

    df.to_excel("escolas.xlsx", index=False)

    print(resultado)
```

Comment: What error are you getting my fellow brazilian friend?

Comment: Hello! Im a begginer in programming. **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Webscraping\web.py", line 51, in <module>
    df.loc[df[row["NOME"]], ["OBS"]] = resultado
  File "C:Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3505, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\admma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3623, in get_loc        
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'ALLYCE GABRIELLY DOS ANJOS LEAL'
PS E:\Webscraping> ** Muito Obrigado!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed you are correct finding the problem.
The problem lies with `df[row["NOME"]]`, which looks for a column named with the name of the person and hence gives a key error because it is not there.
What you want is `df.loc[(df["Name"] == row["Name"]),"OBS"] = resultado`.

However, that is a bad approach considering the scenario where you have two people with the same name (the "OBS" value would be for all the same, namely with the weight and height of the last one). It is best to use the index to locate your rows.

`df.loc[index,"OBS"]= resultado`

PS: move the `df.to_excel()` line outside of the for loop so that you only store it in the end.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Works perfectly! Muito Obrigado!